# Create Case with Activity through Rest API

Tags: c#, rest, acumatica

I am trying to import cases from our old ticketing system into Acumatica using a C# console application. I have the old tickets loaded, and I am trying to use the REST API to create the cases.

I created a custom web service endpoint to load the cases, but I would also like to create message activities from the posts in our old system. If I use the Cases screen under Organization, I can add a Detail entity for activities.  However, there does not appear to be a way to add the Activity Details field, which is the body of the activity.  Here is a screenshot of the current endpoint setup showing the top-level Case entity I created:

[image: Web Service Endpoints]

The above image shows the Case entity, which does not appear to have the ActivityDetails field.  However, if I use the Activity screen from the Hidden site map folder, the ActivityDetails is present.  Here is a screenshot of the Activity entity I created, which does have ActivityDetails:

[image: Activity Object]

I hope this makes sense, but I would like the ActivityDetails field to be available from the Cases top-level entity so I can insert a complete case including activities and their detail.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a behavior that is possible.

The reason for this is that when you go on that screen using the UI, there is no possibility to add new Event, Task or Activity directly from that screen. The action button that are there only serve as to open the other screens a already create a link to the case from where the action was clicked on.

Since the APIs work by dealing with one screen at the time, it is not possible from the Case screen to create an Activity.

So to create an Activity for a Case, you will first have to create the Activity and then link it to the Case.

In order to do so, you must first add some field to both the Case entity and the Activity Entity.
These fields must be added manually as they are not part of the autocompletion.
For the Case entity, you need to add the following field:

```
Field Name = "NoteID"
Mapped Object = "Case Summary"
Mapped Field = "NoteID"
Field Value = "GuidValue"
```

[image: Case Entity definition]`enter code here`
For the Activity entity please add the following field:`enter code here`

```
Field Name = "RefNoteID"
Mapped Object = "Activities"
Mapped Field = "RefNoteID"
Field Value = "GuidValue"
```

[image: Activity Entity definition]
Once these two fields have been added, you can start adding the activity to the case.
In order to do so:

1) Retrieve the Case on which you want to add the activity using A GET call. You will need to use the value from the NoteID field that has just been added.
[image: GET Call use to retrieve the case + Response]

2) Create the Activity like you normally would, using a PUT call, but instead of trying to add a value in the RelatedEntityDescription field, add the NoteID value you just retrieved from the Case to the RefNoteID field you just added to the Activity entity. In the response you will be able to see that the Activity was linked to the case by checking the RelatedEntityDescription field.
[image: Put Call used to create Activity + Response]

Comment: Samol, thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question.  This looks like exactly what I need to do.  I knew I was missing something.

Comment: That is great, can you please look at my question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455895/acumatica-api-add-attache-an-activity-or-note-entity-to-another-entity-i-e-cu

Comment: This works great for me with one exception. If I create the Case, or in my case, Lead with the api and then immediately afterwards try to attach a note to it. It creates the note but doesn't relate it to the case. However, if I manually go create a note then all api calls to create one afterwards will create and relate just fine. Any idea?