# Acumatica API: Add/attache an Activity or Note entity to another entity (i.e. Customer, Contact, or Opportunity)

Tags: c#, .net, acumatica

I am able to add an Activity entity and able to get the NoteId, but not able to add this activity to a specific entity (or attache it after creation), how can I achieve this either using the Rest API or using the good old WSDL webservice?

Comment: Could you please share the processes that you have tried. that way we can start from there and see what went wrong.

Comment: I can see that you have found the similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44961448/create-case-with-activity-through-rest-api/44977998?noredirect=1#comment106951401_44977998) and it should work the same way.